# Data validation for millions of rows in ETL testing

Tags: etl

How do we validate the data for millions of records in an ETL testing process at a stretchy (without doing validation on sample records between source and Target

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up test data that covers all the logic scenarios in your ETL code - including field values that are transformed and field values that should remain untouched
2. Perform record counts on your sources and targets to ensure that the correct number or records are being moved

Comment: But I don't want to do validation on sample test data instead I need to do data validation on all millions of  records. I know it's impossible to do it in manual way .Is their any automated way to do it?